# Gitlab 6.0 is not creating new repository

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to create a new project in 6.0. Gitlab says that repository was created successfully, but there is no repository created.

I was able to create project with repositories before. Suddenly these newly created repositories are not published on server.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please switch in your gitlab install directory and run these commands to check your installation. Maybe something is not running:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Yeah, I exeucuted these two commands.. Everything is fine.. All installation details is in green colour as suggested in the installation guide..

Comment: Production log file says this:

Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Creating scope :opened. Overwriting existing method Issue.opened.
Creating scope :of_projects. Overwriting existing method MergeRequest.of_projects.
Creating scope :closed. Overwriting existing method MergeRequest.closed.
Creating scope :public. Overwriting existing method Snippet.public.
Creating scope :private. Overwriting existing method Snippet.private.

Hope this is bit clear.

Comment: Application.log file says:

August 29, 2013 14:14: X created a new project "X / testing" August 29, 2013 14:19: Administrator created a new project "Administrator / Sample" August 29, 2013 14:25: Project "testing" was removed August 29, 2013 14:25: X created a new project "X / testing" August 29, 2013 14:34: Project "testing" was removed

As we can see, here everything seems correct